# How do I set state from a child component that requires a function to set state with react-dates?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, setstate, react-props, react-dates

I'm using react-date to try to set state of dates that are selected:

```
<DateRangePicker 
  ...
  onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, 
  endDate })} 
  ...
/> // PropTypes.func.isRequired
```

This works fine if it is in the main component where the state lives, but I now have the DateRangePicker in a child component of that component, so I can't just set the state from the child.

I've tried writing a function that lives in the parent component to set the state, but this isn't working:

In the child component:

```
<DateRangePicker 
  ...
  onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => props.onDatesChange({ startDate, 
  endDate })}
  ...
/>
```

In the parent component:

```
onDatesChange = (startDate, endDate) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate,
      endDate
    })
  };
```

Although this works for another parameter in DateRangePicker that sets the state in the parent:

In the child:

```
<DateRangePicker 
  ...
  onFocusChange={props.onFocusChange}
  ...
/>
```

In the parent:

```
  onFocusChange = focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling `props.onDatesChange` with an object, but the parent component's `onDatesChange` function takes two parameters.

```
// Parent:
onDatesChange = (startDate, endDate) => {

// Child:
props.onDatesChange({ startDate, endDate })
```

I would probably change the parent to take an object, to keep it consistent with the other similar functions.